# How to fuse two filters into one table using select in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck with my page, because I'm using two different 'select' options in HTML. I have my script and individually works fine, but when I try to use both filters, one nulls the other and so on... please help me known how to fuse these two filters to work together.

```js
$.getJSON("data.json", function(data){
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val){
        items.push("<tr>");
        items.push("<td Sucursal= ''"+key+"''>"+val.nombreSucursal+"</td>");
        items.push("<td Ciudad= ''"+key+"''>"+val.direccion.municipio+"</td>");
        items.push("<td Lun-Sab= ''"+key+"''>"+val.horarios.Lun_Sab+"</td>");
        items.push("<td Domingo= ''"+key+"''>"+val.horarios.Domingo+"</td>");
        items.push("<td Horario= ''"+key+"''>"+val.horarios.horario+"</td>");
        items.push("<td Contacto= ''"+key+"''>"+val.contacto.telefono+"</td>");
        items.push("</tr>");
    });

    $("<tbody/>",{html: items.join("")}).appendTo("#tablita");
});

$('#filtro').change( function(e) {
    var letter = $(this).val();
    if (letter == 'ALL') {
        $('tr').show();
      }else {
        $('tr').each( function(rowIdx,tr) {
          $(this).hide().find('td').each( function(idx, td) {
            if(idx===0||idx===1||idx===2) {
              var check = $(this).text();
                if (check && check.indexOf(letter) == 0) {
                  $(tr).show();
                    }
                  }
                });
              });
            }
          });

          $('#filtro2').change( function(e) {
            var letter = $(this).val();
              if (letter == 'ALL') {
                  $ ('tr').show ();
              }
              else {
                  $('tr').each( function(rowIdx,tr) {
                      $(this).hide().find('td').each( function(idx, td) {
                          if(idx === 3) {
                              var check = $(this).text();
                              if (check && check.indexOf(letter) == 0) {
                                  $(tr).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
              }
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <!-- IDEA: estilos de pagina -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <LINK rel="StyleSheet" HREF="css/normalize.css"  >
    <LINK rel="StyleSheet" HREF="css/estilo.css"  >
    <LINK rel="StyleSheet" HREF="css/bootstrap.css"  >
    <LINK rel="StyleSheet" HREF="css/contact-buttons.css"  >
    <LINK rel="StyleSheet" HREF="css/demo.css"  >
    <LINK rel="StyleSheet" HREF="css/estiloReceta.css"  >
    <LINK rel="StyleSheet" HREF="css/estiloRegistro.css"  >
    <LINK rel="StyleSheet" HREF="css/inicio.css"  >
    <LINK rel="StyleSheet" HREF="css/jquery-ui.css"  >
    <title>Horarios</title>
    <!-- IDEA: CONTROLADORES DE LA PAGINA PRINCIPAL -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="css/estiloReceta.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/pdfFromHTML.js"></script>
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
                  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
                <![endif]-->

    <!--<script>
        var miAplicacion = angular.module('SCH', []);
        miAplicacion.filter('unique', function () {
            return function (collection, keyname) {
                var output = [],
                        keys = [];

                angular.forEach(collection, function (item) {
                    var key = item[keyname];
                    if (keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                        keys.push(key);
                        output.push(item);
                    }
                });

                return output;
            };
        });
        miAplicacion.controller('controladorBD', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                  $scope.sucursales = [

                ]
            }]);
    </script>-->
    <script>
        function cargaSeccion(div, fichero) {
            $('.' + div).fadeOut(50, function () {
                $('.' + div).html(fichero);
            });
            $('.' + div).fadeIn(50);
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <header>
    <div class="header">
          <!--<img src="img/SHC.png" alt="Sucahersa" height="20%">-->
          <h1>SUCURSALES</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
  <body>
    <!-- IDEA: ".....................................................................................CONTROLADORES DE PAGINA ORIGINAL.................................." -->
    <script src="js/demo.js"></script>
    <div id="pdf2htmldiv" class="container-fluid cabecera">
        <center>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid barmenu">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#defaultNavbar1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.php">INICIO</a></div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="defaultNavbar1">


                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="../nosotros.html">QUIENES SOMOS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="catalogo.php">SUCURSALES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../productos.php">PRODUCTOS MAYOREO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../productos2.php">PRODUCTOS MENUDEO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../recetas/catalogo.php">RECETARIO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../contacto.html">CONTACTO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../solicitud.html">BOLSA DE TRABAJO</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- IDEA: ".....................................................FIN DE LOS CONTROLADORES............................................................................." -->

<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="filtrado">
    <h3 style= "padding-left: 40%; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; line-height: 40px; background-color: orange;">Fines de Semana</h3>
    <label for="buscador">Buscar: </label>

    <select class="" name="filtrado" id="filtro">
      <option value="">Ciudad</option>
      <option value="Salamanca">Salamanca</option>
      <option value="León">León</option>
      <option value="Celaya">Celaya</option>
      <option value="Moroleon">Moroleon</option>
      <option value="Cortazar">Cortazar</option>
      <option value="Juventino">Juventino Rosas</option>
      <option value="Guanajuato">Guanajuato</option>
      <option value="Irapuato">Irapuato</option>
      <option value="Julian">San Julian</option>
      <option value="Sialo">Sialo</option>
      <option value="Uriangato">Uriangato</option>
      <option value="Valle">Valle de Santiago</option>

    </select>
    <select class="" name="filtrado" id="filtro2">
      <option value="">Domingos</option>
      <option value="Si">Si</option>
      <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>

  </div>
  <div id="divtabla">
    <div id="divfondo">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="tablita" >
        <thead> <!-- IDEA:cabecera de la tabla ----------------------------------------------------------->
          <tr>
            <th>Sucursal</th>
            <th>Ciudad</th>
            <th>Lun-Sab</th>
            <th>Domingo</th>
            <th>Horario</th>
            <th>Contacto</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                   <!-- cuerpo de la tabla  --------------------------------------------------------------->
        </tbody>

      </table>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div>

      <center>
          <p class="derechos">® Super Carnicerías Hernández S.A. de C.V. Todos los Derechos Reservados 2018 .</p>

      </center>
  </div>
      </div>










      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui_1.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

      <script>


      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have references to AngularJS in your code, but using event handlers like this is not the AngularJS way. Also, please read [mcve] for hints on how to remove about 90% of your code so that others don't have to wade through it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a way to filter on multiple filter functions, you will need to store an array of filters (or a filter object).

Then just loop through each row and call `filters.every` to ensure that all the criteria is matched across all the filters.

```js
(function($) {
  /* where column is indexed from 1 */
  $.fn.fromTableColumn = function($table, column) {
    return this.append($table.find('tbody td:nth-child(' + column + ')')
        .map((i, td) => $(td).text()).toArray()
        .filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i)
        .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
        .map((val, i) => new Option(val, val)))
      .prepend(new Option('ALL', 'ALL'))
      .find('option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
  }
})(jQuery);

var filters = [
  // City filter
  function($row, index, query) {
    if (query[0].value === 'ALL') return true;
    return $row.find('td:nth-child(3)').text().trim() === query[0].value;
  },
  // Country filter
  function($row, index, query) {
    if (query[1].value === 'ALL') return true;
    return $row.find('td:nth-child(4)').text().trim() === query[1].value;
  }
];

// Populate drop-downs from column values.
$('select[name="city"]').fromTableColumn($('#people'), 3);
$('select[name="country"]').fromTableColumn($('#people'), 4);

// Filter on any of the drop-downs.
$('select[name="city"], select[name="country"]').on('change', function(e) {
  var query = $('form[name="filters"]').serializeArray();
  $('#people tbody tr').each((i, tr) => {
    $(tr).toggle(filters.every(filter => filter($(tr), i, query)));
  });
});
```

```css
.filter-lbl {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="filters">
  <span class="filter-lbl">
    <label>City:</label>
    <select name="city"></select>
  </span>
  <span class="filter-lbl">
    <label>Country:</label>
    <select name="country"></select>
  </span>
</form>
<!-- Generated 100 rows of random data from: https://www.generatedata.com/ -->
<table id="people" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Street</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Richard Carson</td>
      <td>6621 A Street</td>
      <td>Middlesbrough</td>
      <td>Gambia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Neil Carter</td>
      <td>467 Turpis. Rd.</td>
      <td>Eernegem</td>
      <td>Kyrgyzstan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Chester Leach</td>
      <td>3259 Sapien. Avenue</td>
      <td>Burcht</td>
      <td>Guam</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gareth Orr</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 818, 9867 Dolor St.</td>
      <td>Motala</td>
      <td>French Southern Territories</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bruno Avila</td>
      <td>Ap #961-6695 Proin Road</td>
      <td>Brunn am Gebirge</td>
      <td>Tuvalu</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dolan Wyatt</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 753, 5072 Quis Road</td>
      <td>Orai</td>
      <td>Pitcairn Islands</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Malik Larson</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 500, 7399 Eros Street</td>
      <td>Jolanda di Savoia</td>
      <td>Jamaica</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Moses Davenport</td>
      <td>699-620 Erat, Street</td>
      <td>Mont-Saint-AndrŽ</td>
      <td>Madagascar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bevis Mcgee</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 822, 9692 Non, Avenue</td>
      <td>Frankfurt</td>
      <td>Ghana</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Octavius Mcintyre</td>
      <td>Ap #539-4942 Accumsan Avenue</td>
      <td>Toowoomba</td>
      <td>Zimbabwe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tate Morales</td>
      <td>295-327 Nec, Ave</td>
      <td>Gualdo Cattaneo</td>
      <td>Iceland</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orson Boyer</td>
      <td>611-2727 Mi St.</td>
      <td>Midway</td>
      <td>Bahrain</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ira Nguyen</td>
      <td>6999 Sed Rd.</td>
      <td>Kurnool</td>
      <td>Gabon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nigel Fernandez</td>
      <td>Ap #609-8173 Dictum St.</td>
      <td>Seborga</td>
      <td>Central African Republic</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Camden Burke</td>
      <td>158-6818 Tellus Av.</td>
      <td>Raipur</td>
      <td>Aruba</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brendan Quinn</td>
      <td>406-4678 Nullam Rd.</td>
      <td>Langen</td>
      <td>Togo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Plato Bradshaw</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 210, 1406 Amet, Rd.</td>
      <td>Villers-la-Bonne-Eau</td>
      <td>Niue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bernard Langley</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 709, 8927 Convallis Rd.</td>
      <td>Burnaby</td>
      <td>Egypt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lamar Hull</td>
      <td>433-8524 Mauris Rd.</td>
      <td>Beaumont</td>
      <td>Bermuda</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mohammad Mosley</td>
      <td>147 Non, Ave</td>
      <td>Burlington</td>
      <td>Barbados</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Macon Knapp</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 899, 2310 Dui St.</td>
      <td>Molina</td>
      <td>Norfolk Island</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Reece Mcgowan</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 247, 8448 Sed Street</td>
      <td>Silchar</td>
      <td>Seychelles</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Buckminster Wilder</td>
      <td>491-3952 Non, Road</td>
      <td>Hamme</td>
      <td>Cyprus</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mason Hale</td>
      <td>5860 Semper. Ave</td>
      <td>Kanpur</td>
      <td>Antigua and Barbuda</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hayes Rocha</td>
      <td>378-4706 Est, Av.</td>
      <td>Jedburgh</td>
      <td>Estonia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dennis Odom</td>
      <td>Ap #106-8001 Turpis. Av.</td>
      <td>Oostkerke</td>
      <td>Argentina</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Byron Irwin</td>
      <td>Ap #604-8206 Nec Avenue</td>
      <td>Tofield</td>
      <td>Senegal</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lucius Pugh</td>
      <td>1856 Nullam St.</td>
      <td>Hennigsdorf</td>
      <td>Reunion</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John Munoz</td>
      <td>5715 Nec Rd.</td>
      <td>Bazzano</td>
      <td>Slovenia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sebastian Woodward</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 174, 4655 Dignissim Av.</td>
      <td>Tramatza</td>
      <td>Latvia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alan Bass</td>
      <td>682-7253 Sit Rd.</td>
      <td>Naihati</td>
      <td>Togo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Amos Moody</td>
      <td>922-9157 Eleifend Road</td>
      <td>Francofonte</td>
      <td>Bhutan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cameron Gaines</td>
      <td>8015 Dictum St.</td>
      <td>Cádiz</td>
      <td>San Marino</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Louis Marks</td>
      <td>Ap #869-9882 Amet, Avenue</td>
      <td>Caplan</td>
      <td>Papua New Guinea</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wyatt Whitley</td>
      <td>1648 Ante Rd.</td>
      <td>Greenlaw</td>
      <td>Tokelau</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hayden Vang</td>
      <td>1818 Laoreet Street</td>
      <td>Bellefontaine</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Deacon Chen</td>
      <td>9849 Facilisis, St.</td>
      <td>San Joaquín</td>
      <td>Korea, South</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Flynn Finch</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 818, 5177 Nisi St.</td>
      <td>Masullas</td>
      <td>Benin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Calvin Bullock</td>
      <td>592-8245 Scelerisque St.</td>
      <td>Mount Gambier</td>
      <td>Samoa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Forrest Clay</td>
      <td>Ap #971-894 Duis Rd.</td>
      <td>Winchester</td>
      <td>Puerto Rico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Denton Bean</td>
      <td>598-8019 Ut Street</td>
      <td>Camborne</td>
      <td>Philippines</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Merrill Hebert</td>
      <td>Ap #944-757 Tempor Road</td>
      <td>Athens</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael Nielsen</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 345, 8960 Neque. Rd.</td>
      <td>Borchtlombeek</td>
      <td>Niger</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Flynn Stewart</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 869, 9873 Sem Avenue</td>
      <td>Nampa</td>
      <td>Madagascar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Moses Patton</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 357, 2365 Elementum, Av.</td>
      <td>Wanganui</td>
      <td>Pakistan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brian Mcmillan</td>
      <td>568-2969 Quam. Avenue</td>
      <td>Eckville</td>
      <td>Guyana</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Clarke Harper</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 866, 1664 Vel Rd.</td>
      <td>Snellegem</td>
      <td>Swaziland</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Logan Smith</td>
      <td>472-5932 Metus. Street</td>
      <td>Hindupur</td>
      <td>Venezuela</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yuli Duncan</td>
      <td>9233 Nec Road</td>
      <td>Huntsville</td>
      <td>Tajikistan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Deacon Stephens</td>
      <td>4355 Gravida St.</td>
      <td>Matagami</td>
      <td>Lesotho</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alec Young</td>
      <td>567-2317 Mauris Avenue</td>
      <td>Fiuminata</td>
      <td>Gibraltar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Allistair Wall</td>
      <td>336-6059 Lorem Av.</td>
      <td>Marzabotto</td>
      <td>Hong Kong</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Aladdin Dalton</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 960, 6807 Semper Rd.</td>
      <td>Alingsås</td>
      <td>American Samoa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mohammad Ortega</td>
      <td>9131 Cursus Rd.</td>
      <td>Sainte-Marie-Chevigny</td>
      <td>Australia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Channing Sims</td>
      <td>262-2797 Cum Rd.</td>
      <td>Bay Roberts</td>
      <td>Norfolk Island</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vincent Wilder</td>
      <td>1128 Nulla St.</td>
      <td>Alix</td>
      <td>Burundi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Aquila Potts</td>
      <td>6867 Eu Rd.</td>
      <td>Dolcedo</td>
      <td>Bhutan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Camden Walsh</td>
      <td>714-6132 Neque. Road</td>
      <td>Luckenwalde</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Colton Barrera</td>
      <td>593-3535 Ac Rd.</td>
      <td>Moffat</td>
      <td>Korea, North</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jonah Orr</td>
      <td>9614 Phasellus Ave</td>
      <td>Chichester</td>
      <td>Saint Martin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Armand Bridges</td>
      <td>Ap #248-9489 Facilisis, St.</td>
      <td>Vaux-sous-ChŽvremont</td>
      <td>Somalia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kirk Landry</td>
      <td>Ap #927-7484 A Av.</td>
      <td>Torchiarolo</td>
      <td>Afghanistan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Armand Hess</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 348, 4735 Adipiscing Road</td>
      <td>Araban</td>
      <td>Ukraine</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Plato Perez</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 634, 6948 In Rd.</td>
      <td>Rutten</td>
      <td>Azerbaijan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wallace Knox</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 310, 1187 Proin Ave</td>
      <td>Pitt Meadows</td>
      <td>Norway</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dean Kinney</td>
      <td>571-9795 At Avenue</td>
      <td>Municipal District</td>
      <td>Saint Kitts and Nevis</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Baker Sykes</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 645, 7700 Proin Ave</td>
      <td>Denver</td>
      <td>United States</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Moses Maxwell</td>
      <td>Ap #600-7082 Curabitur St.</td>
      <td>Halifax</td>
      <td>Equatorial Guinea</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Raphael Blackwell</td>
      <td>433-4658 Sed Av.</td>
      <td>Matamata</td>
      <td>Mauritius</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Prescott Robertson</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 186, 7338 Rhoncus. Street</td>
      <td>Cawdor</td>
      <td>Mali</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Channing Howard</td>
      <td>3513 Quisque Rd.</td>
      <td>Marbella</td>
      <td>Nicaragua</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jermaine Jacobson</td>
      <td>409-889 Nibh St.</td>
      <td>Adelaide</td>
      <td>Puerto Rico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Austin Beard</td>
      <td>4935 Feugiat Road</td>
      <td>Portland</td>
      <td>Panama</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gage Hodge</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 181, 5628 Non, Rd.</td>
      <td>Essene</td>
      <td>Pakistan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Conan Collier</td>
      <td>6727 Orci St.</td>
      <td>Cambridge</td>
      <td>France</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Melvin Mendez</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 502, 2510 Et, Road</td>
      <td>Aurora</td>
      <td>Bolivia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hayden Moreno</td>
      <td>Ap #560-8618 Nunc Av.</td>
      <td>Ergani</td>
      <td>South Sudan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Richard Goodwin</td>
      <td>5763 Imperdiet Rd.</td>
      <td>Paulatuk</td>
      <td>Niue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Buckminster Arnold</td>
      <td>6972 Morbi Rd.</td>
      <td>South Burlington</td>
      <td>Virgin Islands, United States</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jared Stone</td>
      <td>999-4299 Posuere St.</td>
      <td>Auburn</td>
      <td>India</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orlando Cruz</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 551, 1657 Nunc Rd.</td>
      <td>Vaux-lez-Rosieres</td>
      <td>Micronesia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kareem Shaw</td>
      <td>931-7301 Dolor. Ave</td>
      <td>Empoli</td>
      <td>Libya</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Robert Burton</td>
      <td>9688 Enim. Rd.</td>
      <td>Mönchengladbach</td>
      <td>Tunisia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nigel Patrick</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 167, 1508 Dis St.</td>
      <td>Weston-super-Mare</td>
      <td>Croatia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Chancellor Nichols</td>
      <td>4908 Ligula Road</td>
      <td>Merdorp</td>
      <td>Mongolia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Xavier Herrera</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 130, 5305 Morbi Rd.</td>
      <td>Friedrichsdorf</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Caesar Mercer</td>
      <td>269-3646 Eu, Road</td>
      <td>Wrocław</td>
      <td>Hong Kong</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Colby Fuller</td>
      <td>357-1140 Dignissim. Rd.</td>
      <td>Pilibhit</td>
      <td>Macao</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vladimir Kelley</td>
      <td>Ap #823-3173 At, St.</td>
      <td>Corswarem</td>
      <td>Bosnia and Herzegovina</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Elmo Henry</td>
      <td>Ap #869-5094 Scelerisque Av.</td>
      <td>Mogliano</td>
      <td>United Kingdom (Great Britain)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lionel Kirby</td>
      <td>2520 Lacinia. Av.</td>
      <td>Tuktoyaktuk</td>
      <td>Saint Barthélemy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Aristotle Butler</td>
      <td>8632 Morbi Av.</td>
      <td>Hannover</td>
      <td>Mauritania</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Solomon Caldwell</td>
      <td>Ap #963-1044 Nullam St.</td>
      <td>Bala</td>
      <td>Nigeria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>William Warren</td>
      <td>Ap #343-1419 Porttitor Road</td>
      <td>Deventer</td>
      <td>Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Erasmus Berry</td>
      <td>4755 Odio. Rd.</td>
      <td>Yahyalı</td>
      <td>Nepal</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Roth England</td>
      <td>516-6743 Nulla Road</td>
      <td>Malbaie</td>
      <td>Virgin Islands, British</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ralph Nunez</td>
      <td>235-9985 Augue Street</td>
      <td>Aurora</td>
      <td>Norfolk Island</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jacob Acosta</td>
      <td>273-4139 Et Street</td>
      <td>Cranbrook</td>
      <td>Mauritius</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wang Frye</td>
      <td>P.O. Box 362, 2794 Nulla. Ave</td>
      <td>Scunthorpe</td>
      <td>Oman</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Aaron Rodriquez</td>
      <td>Ap #255-9265 Nec Av.</td>
      <td>Santa Maria a Monte</td>
      <td>Malawi</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```